# Do countries inform each other about ballistic missile test launches?

Tags: international-relations, military, nuclear-weapons

Informing potential adversaries about intercontinental ballistic missile (ICBM) test looks logical, to not trigger false alert.

I can't find any info - do countries do it? Do some protocols exist for this?

Examples of recent ICBM launches:

[by USA](https://gizmodo.com/air-force-successfully-launches-first-icbm-test-of-the-1825558054)

[by Russia](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/30/russia-tests-its-new-nuclear-intercontinental-ballistic-missile.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an agreement between the US and Russia, that specifically coordinates notifications of test flights for ICBMs in order to prevent nuclear war. It is the [Ballistic Missile Launch Notification Agreement](https://www.state.gov/t/isn/4714.htm), started 1988.

This is referenced again, several times, in the Strategic Arms Reduction Treaty (START), since expired, and the current New Strategic Arms Reduction Treaty ([New START](https://www.state.gov/t/avc/newstart/c44126.htm)).